# Dynamics CRM setFormNotification in Quick Create Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I've made a Javascript to prevent from saving a Lead if the fields Phone Number, Mail or Business Phone are empty. If any of these fields are empty, I use a setFormNotification to let the user know it's not possible to save.

My problem arises when I uses the same code for Lead Quick Create Form and the setFormNotification do not shown. When I run debug the setFormNotification shows a value of false, but I can't seem to find anything in the SDK that says setFormNotification aren't avaible for Qick Create Forms.

Another strange thing is that the Quick Create Form shows a form notification if any of the required fileds aren't filled in, so it shows that form notification could be shown, but in my case: not from my JavaScript.

Does anyone know why this occurs? And does anyone know how to show a Form Notification in a Quick Create Form?

Comment: Can you post your code please

Answer (score 0):

As per this [blog](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/140325.aspx), It seems that `setFormNotification` does not work for Quick Create Forms. I still have to validate this with CRM 2015 Forms.